# JavaScript: Show decimals in fraction format

Tags: javascript, fractions

I want to make a ml to oz converter and present the remaining decimal in fraction formats 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, etc... As example 50 ml would be 1 <sup>2/3</sup> oz. The integer is on the left side, and the decimal on the right side is showing in fraction format.

I understand that the formula to convert ml to oz is:

```
ml * 0.03381
```

50 * 0.03381 = 1.6905. The decimal .6905 would be rounded to 2/3 (0.66666666666) so the fraction part is presented in a readable format.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a list of wanted fractions?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz. I think each 5% should be enough. I have updated the original post.

Comment: now you never get some thirds.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a nice suggestion? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `approximateFraction` function, that can take in a decimal and a maxDenominator, and you can use that in a ml to Oz converter. Right now this limits the maximum denominator of conversion to 10. and that gives `50ml` -> `1 7/10`. You can reduce the maximum denominator to a lower number if you set it to 5 or 6 then it will give you `1 2/3` instead.

```js
function approximateFraction(decimal, maxDenominator) {
  let numerator = 1;
  let denominator = 1;
  let minError = Math.abs(decimal - (numerator / denominator));

  for (let d = 2; d <= maxDenominator; d++) {
    const n = Math.round(decimal * d);
    const error = Math.abs(decimal - (n / d));

    if (error < minError) {
      minError = error;
      numerator = n;
      denominator = d;
    }
  }

  return [numerator, denominator];
}

function mlToOzAndFraction(ml, maxDenominator) {
  const oz = ml * 0.033814;
  const integerPart = Math.floor(oz);
  const decimalPart = oz - integerPart;
  const [numerator, denominator] = approximateFraction(decimalPart, maxDenominator);
  const ozFraction = numerator !== 0 ? `${numerator}/${denominator}` : '';
  return `${integerPart}${ozFraction ? ' ' : ''}${ozFraction} oz`;
}

console.log('Max denominator 10: ', mlToOzAndFraction(50, 10)); // 50ml -> 1 7/10 oz
console.log('Max denominator 5: ', mlToOzAndFraction(50, 5)); // 50ml -> 1 2/3 oz
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Setting denominator to 6 gives a real nice end result :)